# How to access jquery change event value outside the method?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have an input text field:

```
<input type="text" id="from_input" class="form-control" placeholder="FROM">
```

I want to get the value of text when it changes. Here is my jquery code:

```
<script>
  var fromValue;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#from_input").change(function() {
      fromValue = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(fromValue);
  });
</script>
```

I am getting fromValue variable as undefined. I need to get the text field value for further calculation in whole script. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `fromValue` will only have some value when `#from_input` is changed... You'll need to change your logic or maybe [trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) a change on `#from_input` before logging the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are logging the `fromValue` variable before the change event has fired.

Your code needs to be updated to log the variable *inside* of the closure:

```
<script>
  var fromValue;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#from_input").change(function() {
      fromValue = $(this).val();
      console.log(fromValue);
    });
  });
</script>
```

If you attempt to access fromValue outside of this inner function, it will be undefined. Only within the inner function (more precisely, after the inner function is called) will it have a value.

If you want to use the value, you'll need to pass it from inside the function, e.g.

```
$("#from_input").change(function() {
  do_something($(this).val());
});
```

where `do_something` is defined elsewhere in the code and performs the further calculation you're trying to do.

You should read up on [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1355166) as that's what you're dealing with here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event argument. The event contains the target element. And I noticed that you `console.log` is outside the callback function. Your code probably works already but you just don't see it.

```
<script>
  var fromValue;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#from_input").change(function(event) {
      fromValue = event.target.value;
      console.log(fromValue);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#itext').keyup(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('#result').text('Your text: ' + text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="itext">
<br><label id="result">Your text: </label>
```